# How to place circles around specific data points on a scatter plot in R?

Tags: r

My question is two fold:

1) Is it possible to place a circle around specific data points on a scatter plot in R?

2) If so, how would I place separate circles of a defined radius around (5, 6) and (18, 23) given the following data.

```
x <- c(2, 5, 7, 9, 12, 16, 18, 21)
y <- c(3, 6, 10, 13, 15, 19, 23, 25)
plot(x, y)
```

(NB: This is not a request to colour specific data points on the plot, but to place a circle around them)

Comment: Do you mean circles with the same radius?

Comment: It's not clear if you mean one circle encompassing both points, or 2 circles - one around each point.

Comment: Thanks for asking for clarification.  I mean separate circles (1 around each point) of a defined radius of the same size.

Comment: To me, defined radius =/= same radius, i.e. you can define different radius or the same radius.

Comment: Ah, thank-you again. I mean circles of the same radius which I have defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the `?symbols` help page for drawing circles

```
x <- c(2, 5, 7, 9, 12, 16, 18, 21)
y <- c(3, 6, 10, 13, 15, 19, 23, 25)
plot(x, y)
symbols(x=c(5,18), y=c(6,23), circles=rep(1,2), add=T, inches=F)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I also discovered the circles can be coloured by using `symbols(x=c(5,18), y=c(6,23), circles=rep(1,2), add=T, inches=F, fg = "red")`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `symbols` function in base R, where the `size` vector is the radius you want around each point.

```
x <- c(2, 5, 7, 9, 12, 16, 18, 21)
y <- c(3, 6, 10, 13, 15, 19, 23, 25)
plot(x, y)
size=runif(length(x))
symbols(x,y,circles=size)
```